# word2vec gives vectors of very few words in a text.Why?

Tags: word2vec

When I provide a text document as input to word2vec. It assigns vectors to a very few words from the vocabulary of the text. Why does this happen? And how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. It's hard to understand your problem. Please be more precise and show us some of your code. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you are seeing very few vectors being created is that your corpus is too small. Word2vec will remove infrequently occurring words from the vocabulary. This is controlled by the *t-min-count* command line switch. The default for the original source code is set to 5. Any words that occur less than this many times in your corpus will be removed.